# CUDA collect2 ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: hyperlink, compilation, cuda, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to compile Mars for cuda 4.2.9 (cuda 5.0 eliminated a lot of header files used by Mars). Versions below 5.0 seem to utilize this monstrous makefile common.mk and I'm having a hard time configuring it to get the code to work. The object files compile just fine but I'm getting this error:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lcutil_x86_64
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lshrutil_x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/ian/code/cuda-4.2.9/C/bin/linux/release/MatrixMul] Error 1
```

Why is this happening? How can I remedy it?

Here is the makefile for MatrixMul:

```
################################################################################
#
# Build script for project
#
################################################################################

# Add source files here
EXECUTABLE      := MatrixMul
# Cuda source files (compiled with cudacc)
CUFILES         := main.cu MarsLib.cu MarsScan.cu MarsSort.cu
# C/C++ source files (compiled with gcc / c++)
CCFILES         := MarsUtils.cpp


################################################################################
# Rules and targets

include ../cuda-4.2.9/C/common/common.mk
```

The lines of common.mk that I edited:

```
# Basic directory setup for SDK
# (override directories only if they are not already defined)
SRCDIR     ?=
ROOTDIR    ?= /home/ian/code/cuda-4.2.9
ROOTBINDIR ?= $(ROOTDIR)/C/bin
BINDIR     ?= $(ROOTBINDIR)/$(OSLOWER)
ROOTOBJDIR ?= obj
LIBDIR     := $(ROOTDIR)/C/lib
COMMONDIR  := $(ROOTDIR)/C/common
SHAREDDIR  := $(ROOTDIR)/shared/
```

Original values:

```
# Basic directory setup for SDK
# (override directories only if they are not already defined)
SRCDIR     ?= 
ROOTDIR    ?= ..
ROOTBINDIR ?= $(ROOTDIR)/../bin
BINDIR     ?= $(ROOTBINDIR)/$(OSLOWER)
ROOTOBJDIR ?= obj
LIBDIR     := $(ROOTDIR)/../lib
COMMONDIR  := $(ROOTDIR)/../common
SHAREDDIR  := $(ROOTDIR)/../shared/
```

And the whole common.mk:

```
################################################################################
#
# Common build script for CUDA source projects for Linux and Mac platforms
#
################################################################################

.SUFFIXES : .cu .cu_dbg.o .c_dbg.o .cpp_dbg.o .cu_rel.o .c_rel.o .cpp_rel.o .cubin .ptx

# Add new SM Versions here as devices with new Compute Capability are released
SM_VERSIONS   := 10 11 12 13 20 21 30

CUDA_INSTALL_PATH ?= /home/ian/code/cuda-4.2.9/cuda/

ifdef cuda-install
        CUDA_INSTALL_PATH := $(cuda-install)
endif

# detect OS
OSUPPER = $(shell uname -s 2>/dev/null | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])
OSLOWER = $(shell uname -s 2>/dev/null | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])

# 'linux' is output for Linux system, 'darwin' for OS X
DARWIN = $(strip $(findstring DARWIN, $(OSUPPER)))
ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
   SNOWLEOPARD = $(strip $(findstring 10.6, $(shell egrep "<string>10\.6" /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist)))
   LION        = $(strip $(findstring 10.7, $(shell egrep "<string>10\.7" /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist)))
endif

# detect 32-bit or 64-bit platform
HP_64 = $(shell uname -m | grep 64)
OSARCH= $(shell uname -m)

# Basic directory setup for SDK
# (override directories only if they are not already defined)
SRCDIR     ?=
ROOTDIR    ?= /home/ian/code/cuda-4.2.9/cuda/C
ROOTBINDIR ?= $(ROOTDIR)/bin
BINDIR     ?= $(ROOTBINDIR)/$(OSLOWER)
ROOTOBJDIR ?= obj
LIBDIR     := $(ROOTDIR)/lib
COMMONDIR  := $(ROOTDIR)/common
SHAREDDIR  := $(ROOTDIR)/../shared/

# Compilers
NVCC       := $(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/bin/nvcc
CXX        := g++ -fPIC
CC         := gcc -fPIC
LINK       := g++ -fPIC
# Includes
INCLUDES  += -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include -I$(COMMONDIR)/inc -I$(SHAREDDIR)/inc

# Warning flags
CXXWARN_FLAGS := \
        -W -Wall \
        -Wimplicit \
        -Wswitch \
        -Wformat \
        -Wchar-subscripts \
        -Wparentheses \
        -Wmultichar \
        -Wtrigraphs \
        -Wpointer-arith \
        -Wcast-align \
        -Wreturn-type \
        -Wno-unused-function \
        $(SPACE)

CWARN_FLAGS := $(CXXWARN_FLAGS) \
        -Wstrict-prototypes \
        -Wmissing-prototypes \
        -Wmissing-declarations \
        -Wnested-externs \
        -Wmain \

# architecture flag for nvcc and gcc compilers build
CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG :=
CXX_ARCH_FLAGS  :=
NVCCFLAGS       :=
LIB_ARCH        := $(OSARCH)

# Determining the necessary Cross-Compilation Flags
# 32-bit OS, but we target 64-bit cross compilation
ifeq ($(x86_64),1)
    NVCCFLAGS       += -m64
    LIB_ARCH         = x86_64
    ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
         CXX_ARCH_FLAGS += -arch x86_64
    else
         CXX_ARCH_FLAGS += -m64
    endif
else
# 64-bit OS, and we target 32-bit cross compilation
    ifeq ($(i386),1)
        NVCCFLAGS       += -m32
        LIB_ARCH         = i386
        ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
             CXX_ARCH_FLAGS += -arch i386
        else
             CXX_ARCH_FLAGS += -m32
        endif
    else
        ifeq "$(strip $(HP_64))" ""
            LIB_ARCH        = i386
            NVCCFLAGS      += -m32
            ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
               CXX_ARCH_FLAGS += -arch i386
        else
             CXX_ARCH_FLAGS += -m32
        endif
    else
        ifeq "$(strip $(HP_64))" ""
            LIB_ARCH        = i386
            NVCCFLAGS      += -m32
            ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
               CXX_ARCH_FLAGS += -arch i386
            else
               CXX_ARCH_FLAGS += -m32
            endif
        else
            LIB_ARCH        = x86_64
            NVCCFLAGS      += -m64
            ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
               CXX_ARCH_FLAGS += -arch x86_64
            else
               CXX_ARCH_FLAGS += -m64
            endif
        endif
    endif
endif

# Compiler-specific flags (by default, we always use sm_10, sm_20, and sm_30), unless we use the SMVERSION template
GENCODE_SM10 := -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\"
GENCODE_SM20 := -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\"
GENCODE_SM30 := -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\"

CXXFLAGS  += $(CXXWARN_FLAGS) $(CXX_ARCH_FLAGS)
CFLAGS    += $(CWARN_FLAGS) $(CXX_ARCH_FLAGS)
LINKFLAGS +=
LINK      += $(LINKFLAGS) $(CXX_ARCH_FLAGS)

# This option for Mac allows CUDA applications to work without requiring to set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
   LINK += -Xlinker -rpath $(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib
endif

# Common flags
COMMONFLAGS += $(INCLUDES) -DUNIX

# If we are enabling GPU based debugging, then we want to use -G, warning that this
# May have a significant impact on GPU device code, since optimizations are turned off
ifeq ($(gpudbg),1)
    NVCCFLAGS += -G
        dbg = $(gpudbg)
endif

# Debug/release configuration
ifeq ($(dbg),1)
        COMMONFLAGS += -g
    NVCCFLAGS   += -D_DEBUG
        CXXFLAGS    += -D_DEBUG
        CFLAGS      += -D_DEBUG
        BINSUBDIR   := debug
        LIBSUFFIX   := D
else
        COMMONFLAGS += -O2
        BINSUBDIR   := release
        LIBSUFFIX   :=
        NVCCFLAGS   += --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing
        CXXFLAGS    += -fno-strict-aliasing
        CFLAGS      += -fno-strict-aliasing
endif

# architecture flag for cubin build
CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG :=

# OpenGL is used or not (if it is used, then it is necessary to include GLEW)
ifeq ($(USEGLLIB),1)
    ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
        OPENGLLIB := -L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries
        OPENGLLIB += -lGL -lGLU $(COMMONDIR)/lib/$(OSLOWER)/libGLEW.a
    else
# this case for linux platforms
        OPENGLLIB := -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lXmu
# check if x86_64 flag has been set, otherwise, check HP_64 is i386/x86_64
        ifeq ($(x86_64),1)
               OPENGLLIB += -lGLEW_x86_64 -L/usr/X11R6/lib64
        else
             ifeq ($(i386),)
                 ifeq "$(strip $(HP_64))" ""
                     OPENGLLIB += -lGLEW -L/usr/X11R6/lib
                 else
                     OPENGLLIB += -lGLEW_x86_64 -L/usr/X11R6/lib64
                 endif
             endif
        endif
# check if i386 flag has been set, otehrwise check HP_64 is i386/x86_64
        ifeq ($(i386),1)
               OPENGLLIB += -lGLEW -L/usr/X11R6/lib
        else
             ifeq ($(x86_64),)
                 ifeq "$(strip $(HP_64))" ""
                     OPENGLLIB += -lGLEW -L/usr/X11R6/lib
                 else
                     OPENGLLIB += -lGLEW_x86_64 -L/usr/X11R6/lib64
                 endif
             endif
        endif
    endif
endif
ifeq ($(USEGLUT),1)
    ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
        OPENGLLIB += -framework GLUT
    else
        ifeq ($(x86_64),1)
             OPENGLLIB += -lglut -L/usr/lib64
        endif
        ifeq ($(i386),1)
             OPENGLLIB += -lglut -L/usr/lib
        endif

        ifeq ($(x86_64),)
            ifeq ($(i386),)
                OPENGLLIB += -lglut
            endif
        endif
    endif
endif

ifeq ($(USEPARAMGL),1)
        PARAMGLLIB := -lparamgl_$(LIB_ARCH)$(LIBSUFFIX)
endif

ifeq ($(USERENDERCHECKGL),1)
        RENDERCHECKGLLIB := -lrendercheckgl_$(LIB_ARCH)$(LIBSUFFIX)
endif

ifeq ($(USENVCUVID), 1)
     ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
         NVCUVIDLIB := -L../../common/lib/darwin -lnvcuvid
     endif
endif

# Libs
ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
    LIB       := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib -L$(LIBDIR) -L$(COMMONDIR)/lib/$(OSLOWER) -L$(SHAREDDIR)/lib $(NVCUVIDLIB)
else
  ifeq "$(strip $(HP_64))" ""
    ifeq ($(x86_64),1)
       LIB       := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib64 -L$(LIBDIR) -L$(COMMONDIR)/lib/$(OSLOWER) -L$(SHAREDDIR)/lib
    else
       LIB       := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib -L$(LIBDIR) -L$(COMMONDIR)/lib/$(OSLOWER) -L$(SHAREDDIR)/lib
    endif
  else
    ifeq ($(i386),1)
       LIB       := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib -L$(LIBDIR) -L$(COMMONDIR)/lib/$(OSLOWER) -L$(SHAREDDIR)/lib
    else
       LIB       := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib64 -L$(LIBDIR) -L$(COMMONDIR)/lib/$(OSLOWER) -L$(SHAREDDIR)/lib
    endif
  endif
endif
# If dynamically linking to CUDA and CUDART, we exclude the libraries from the LIB
ifeq ($(USECUDADYNLIB),1)
     LIB += ${OPENGLLIB} $(PARAMGLLIB) $(RENDERCHECKGLLIB) ${LIB} -ldl -rdynamic
else
# static linking, we will statically link against CUDA and CUDART
  ifeq ($(USEDRVAPI),1)
     LIB += -lcuda   ${OPENGLLIB} $(PARAMGLLIB) $(RENDERCHECKGLLIB) ${LIB}
  else
     ifeq ($(emu),1)
         LIB += -lcudartemu
     else
         LIB += -lcudart
     endif
     LIB += ${OPENGLLIB} $(PARAMGLLIB) $(RENDERCHECKGLLIB) ${LIB}
  endif
endif

ifeq ($(USECUFFT),1)
  ifeq ($(emu),1)
    LIB += -lcufftemu
  else
    LIB += -lcufft
  endif
endif

ifeq ($(USECUBLAS),1)
  ifeq ($(emu),1)
    LIB += -lcublasemu
  else
    LIB += -lcublas
  endif
endif

ifeq ($(USECURAND),1)
    LIB += -lcurand
endif

ifeq ($(USECUSPARSE),1)
  LIB += -lcusparse
endif

# Lib/exe configuration
# Lib/exe configuration
# Lib/exe configuration
ifneq ($(STATIC_LIB),)
        TARGETDIR := $(LIBDIR)
        TARGET   := $(subst .a,_$(LIB_ARCH)$(LIBSUFFIX).a,$(LIBDIR)/$(STATIC_LIB))
        LINKLINE  = ar rucv $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
else
        ifneq ($(OMIT_CUTIL_LIB),1)
                LIB += -lcutil_$(LIB_ARCH)$(LIBSUFFIX)
        endif
        ifneq ($(OMIT_SHRUTIL_LIB),1)
                LIB += -lshrutil_$(LIB_ARCH)$(LIBSUFFIX)
        endif

        # Device emulation configuration
        ifeq ($(emu), 1)
                NVCCFLAGS   += -deviceemu
                CUDACCFLAGS +=
                BINSUBDIR   := emu$(BINSUBDIR)
                # consistency, makes developing easier
                CXXFLAGS                += -D__DEVICE_EMULATION__
                CFLAGS                  += -D__DEVICE_EMULATION__
        endif
        TARGETDIR := $(BINDIR)/$(BINSUBDIR)
        TARGET    := $(TARGETDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)
        LINKLINE  = $(LINK) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIB)
endif

# check if verbose 
ifeq ($(verbose), 1)
        VERBOSE :=
else
        VERBOSE := @
endif

################################################################################
# Check for input flags and set compiler flags appropriately
################################################################################
ifeq ($(fastmath), 1)
        NVCCFLAGS += -use_fast_math
endif

ifeq ($(keep), 1)
        NVCCFLAGS += -keep
        NVCC_KEEP_CLEAN := *.i* *.cubin *.cu.c *.cudafe* *.fatbin.c *.ptx
endif

ifdef maxregisters
        NVCCFLAGS += -maxrregcount $(maxregisters)
endif

ifeq ($(ptxas), 1)
        NVCCFLAGS += --ptxas-options=-v
endif
# Add cudacc flags
NVCCFLAGS += $(CUDACCFLAGS)

# Add common flags
NVCCFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS  += $(COMMONFLAGS)
CFLAGS    += $(COMMONFLAGS)

ifeq ($(nvcc_warn_verbose),1)
        NVCCFLAGS += $(addprefix --compiler-options ,$(CXXWARN_FLAGS))
        NVCCFLAGS += --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing
endif

################################################################################
# Set up object files
################################################################################
OBJDIR := $(ROOTOBJDIR)/$(LIB_ARCH)/$(BINSUBDIR)
OBJS +=  $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.cpp.o,$(notdir $(CCFILES)))
OBJS +=  $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.c.o,$(notdir $(CFILES)))
OBJS +=  $(patsubst %.cu,$(OBJDIR)/%.cu.o,$(notdir $(CUFILES)))

################################################################################
# Set up cubin output files
################################################################################
CUBINDIR := $(SRCDIR)data
CUBINS +=  $(patsubst %.cu,$(CUBINDIR)/%.cubin,$(notdir $(CUBINFILES)))

################################################################################
# Set up PTX output files
################################################################################
PTXDIR := $(SRCDIR)data
PTXBINS +=  $(patsubst %.cu,$(PTXDIR)/%.ptx,$(notdir $(PTXFILES)))

################################################################################
# Rules
################################################################################
$(OBJDIR)/%.c.o : $(SRCDIR)%.c $(C_DEPS)
        $(VERBOSE)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJDIR)/%.cpp.o : $(SRCDIR)%.cpp $(C_DEPS)
        $(VERBOSE)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

# Default arch includes gencode for sm_10, sm_20, sm_30, and other archs from GENCODE_ARCH declared in the makefile
$(OBJDIR)/%.cu.o : $(SRCDIR)%.cu $(CU_DEPS)
        $(VERBOSE)$(NVCC) $(GENCODE_SM10) $(GENCODE_ARCH) $(GENCODE_SM20) $(GENCODE_SM30) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(SMVERSIONFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

# Default arch includes gencode for sm_10, sm_20, sm_30, and other archs from GENCODE_ARCH declared in the makefile
$(CUBINDIR)/%.cubin : $(SRCDIR)%.cu cubindirectory
        $(VERBOSE)$(NVCC) $(GENCODE_SM10) $(GENCODE_ARCH) $(GENCODE_SM20) $(GENCODE_SM30) $(CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(SMVERSIONFLAGS) -o $@ -cubin $<

$(PTXDIR)/%.ptx : $(SRCDIR)%.cu ptxdirectory
        $(VERBOSE)$(NVCC) $(CUBIN_ARCH_FLAG) $(NVCCFLAGS) $(SMVERSIONFLAGS) -o $@ -ptx $<
# The following definition is a template that gets instantiated for each SM
# version (sm_10, sm_13, etc.) stored in SMVERSIONS.  It does 2 things:
# 1. It adds to OBJS a .cu_sm_XX.o for each .cu file it finds in CUFILES_sm_XX.
# 2. It generates a rule for building .cu_sm_XX.o files from the corresponding 
#    .cu file.
#
# The intended use for this is to allow Makefiles that use common.mk to compile
# files to different Compute Capability targets (aka SM arch version).  To do
# so, in the Makefile, list files for each SM arch separately, like so:
# This will be used over the default rule abov
#
# CUFILES_sm_10 := mycudakernel_sm10.cu app.cu
# CUFILES_sm_12 := anothercudakernel_sm12.cu
#
define SMVERSION_template
#OBJS += $(patsubst %.cu,$(OBJDIR)/%.cu_$(1).o,$(notdir $(CUFILES_$(1))))
OBJS += $(patsubst %.cu,$(OBJDIR)/%.cu_$(1).o,$(notdir $(CUFILES_sm_$(1))))
$(OBJDIR)/%.cu_$(1).o : $(SRCDIR)%.cu $(CU_DEPS)
#       $(VERBOSE)$(NVCC) -o $$@ -c $$< $(NVCCFLAGS)  $(1)
        $(VERBOSE)$(NVCC) -gencode=arch=compute_$(1),code=\"sm_$(1),compute_$(1)\" $(GENCODE_SM20) $(GENCODE_SM30) -o $$@ -c $$< $(NVCCFLAGS)
endef

# This line invokes the above template for each arch version stored in
# SM_VERSIONS.  The call function invokes the template, and the eval
# function interprets it as make commands.
$(foreach smver,$(SM_VERSIONS),$(eval $(call SMVERSION_template,$(smver))))

$(TARGET): makedirectories $(OBJS) $(CUBINS) $(PTXBINS) Makefile
        $(VERBOSE)$(LINKLINE)

cubindirectory:
        $(VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(CUBINDIR)

ptxdirectory:
        $(VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(PTXDIR)

makedirectories:
        $(VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(LIBDIR)
        $(VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
        $(VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(TARGETDIR)


tidy :
        $(VERBOSE)find . | egrep "#" | xargs rm -f
        $(VERBOSE)find . | egrep "\~" | xargs rm -f
clean : tidy
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f *.stub.c *.gpu *.cu.cpp *.i *.ii
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f *.cubin *.ptx *.fatbin.c *.hash
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f *.cudafe1.c *.cudafe2.c *.cudafe1.cpp *.cudafe2.cpp
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(OBJS) 
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(CUBINS)
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(PTXBINS)
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(TARGET)
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(NVCC_KEEP_CLEAN)
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(ROOTBINDIR)/$(OSLOWER)/$(BINSUBDIR)/*.ppm
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(ROOTBINDIR)/$(OSLOWER)/$(BINSUBDIR)/*.pgm
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(ROOTBINDIR)/$(OSLOWER)/$(BINSUBDIR)/*.bin
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(ROOTBINDIR)/$(OSLOWER)/$(BINSUBDIR)/*.bmp
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(ROOTBINDIR)/$(OSLOWER)/$(BINSUBDIR)/*.txt
        $(VERBOSE)rm -f $(CUBINDIR)/*.cubin $(PTXDIR)/*.ptx
        $(VERBOSE)rm -rf $(ROOTOBJDIR)
        $(VERBOSE)rm -rf $(LIBDIR)
        $(VERBOSE)rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
        $(VERBOSE)rm -rf $(TARGETDIR)

clobber : clean
        $(VERBOSE)rm -rf $(COMMONDIR)/lib/*.a
        $(VERBOSE)rm -rf $(SHAREDDIR)/lib/*.a
        $(VERBOSE)rm -rf $(COMMONDIR)/obj
        $(VERBOSE)rm -rf $(SHAREDDIR)/obj
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this happening?

`libcutil_x86_64.lib` and `libshrutil_x86_64.lib` are libraries that are built by the cuda samples (called CUDA SDK in cuda 4.2 and earlier) when a proper `make` operation has been done after the CUDA SDK is installed.  The linker cannot find these libraries and so is throwing these errors.

> How can I remedy it?

1. Make sure that the CUDA 4.2 SDK has been properly installed and that the necessary `make` operation has been done to build the samples and therefore the requisite libraries.  If you're unsure how to install the CUDA SDK or make the sample codes, review the `/home/ian/code/cuda-4.2.9/CUDA_SDK_Release_Notes.txt` file (especially linux install instructions).  You may also be interested in the `GPU_COMPUTING_SDK_Description.rtf` file in that directory and also the files in the `.../doc/release` subdirectory.  If you have not properly built the samples, the libraries won't be available and you'll have no luck linking your own matrixMul-MARS project.  Note that you can specify the directory path to install the CUDA SDK at.  Let's assume that from here on that `...` in a path represents your SDK install path (which might be `/home/ian/code/cuda-4.2.9/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK` or something similar.)  If things are jumbled in what you already have, you may want to start clean and re-run the installer.
2. Create a new project directory for your matrixMul-MARS project, at the same level as the other C source project directories, i.e. `.../C/src/myMARS` or something similar.
3. Copy all the files from `.../C/src/matrixMul` directory into your new `.../C/src/myMARS` directory.
4. Make the necessary changes to the `Makefile` in your new project directory (only) corresponding to what you have shown here, such as including additional files to be built, etc.  *You should not have to make any changes to common.mk.*
5. Now execute `make` in your new project directory.

Comment: Everything works splendidly now, thanks for the detailed instructions.

Comment: @user1743798 can you please mark this as the answer? I was looking but didn't know this worked until I saw your comment